How do I compose or chain multiple function in Python
When writing a program, I often want to perform a series of steps on a piece of data (usually a list or string). For example I might want to call a function which returns a string, convert it to a list, map over the list, and then reduce to get a final result.
In programming languages I've used in the past, I would expect to be able to do something like one of the following:
compose(
  getSomeString,
  list,
  map(someMapFunction)
  reduce(someReduceFunction)
)()

getSomeString()
  .list()
  .map(someMapFunction)
  .reduce(someReduceFunction)

getSomeFunction
  => list
  => map(someMapFunction)
  => reduce(someReduceFunction)()

However, I can't figure out a clean and compact way to do composition/chaining in Python. The one exception I've found is that a list comprehension works for the case where I want to compose a map and a filter.
What is the Pythonic way of writing composition oriented code without either having tons of nesting that makes my code look like Lisp:
reduce(
  someReduceFunction,
  map(
    someMapFunction,
    list(
      getSomeString()
    )
  )
)

Or creating intermediate values for everything:
myString = getSomeString()
stringAsList = list(myString)
mappedString = map(someMapFunction, stringAsList)
reducedString = reduce(someReduceFunction, mappedString)


The problem with chains is that if anything fails in the middle it is often difficult to diagnose the problem. We say lots of questions where people have done just that and don't understand when the see exception messages like: "NoneType has no ...". It is always beetter to check the rsult of each function before proceeding to the next.

The only unpythonic thing I see there is the pointless and wasteful list() call (and perhaps the non-standard indentation).

Check out this library: https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz, it provides utility functions for functional programming, including compose and pipe.

If you don't mind writing your own utility function something like this will do:
def compose(*functions):
  def pipe(value):
    for f in functions:
      value = f(value)
    return value

  return pipe

It works by producing an inner function that iterates over your given functions and passes the output of one to the input of the next.
And then you can use it as:
from functools import partial

compose(
  getSomeString,
  list,
  partial(map, someMapFunction),
  partial(reduce, someReduceFunction)
)("input")

The downside is that it can only pass around single return values. but you could fix this with lambdas:
compose(
  returns_a_dict,
  # Use a lambda to rewrite the single argument the way you want.
  lambda d: takes_kw_args(**d)
)("input")

(PS: I used functools.partial to freeze map together with its map function (call it map_f), so that the pipe function calls f(value) which equals partial(map, map_f)(value) which equals map(map_f, value))

I have to say, in general, Python is a multi-paradigm programming language that can be used for functional programming, but it won't lead to the cleanest slickest looking code like in languages that are strictly functional programming languages.

Would it be considered normal in Python to implement utility functions like that when solving a problem? E.g. if I was answering an interview question would implement a compose or pipe function be considered odd?
I know that some languages like Lisp or shell scripts it's common to build up those sorts of functions while in other languages it's less common. So I guess I'm trying to get a feel for what would be considered normal in the Python community.

Regarding functional programming: That's part of my concern here. Am I trying to twist Python to do things it isn't meant to. Do you have any advice on where I should look to get a better idea of what paradigms/approaches/strategies Python generally favors?

Yes, it's considered normal to make utility functions, take a look at for example the Python itertools docs, it provides you a bunch of "recipes" (aka copy-pastable utility functions), and there's other places where the Python standard library decided not to include some stuff, but they give you readymade code. There's no real reason to shy away from creating little snippet functions like this if they help make your code more readable and understandable.

No you're not doing anything Python isn't supposed to do here. It's just that at some point or another, Guido Van Rossum or whichever person deciding what to put in functools decided not to put it there :p I guess that a lot of people (including me) find that using comprehensions we can do most things without needing to chain functions?

Make a single function to handle chained piece of code. That way you can reuse code also improving readability.

Hello, welcome to SO :D Your answer could benefit from more detail, to instruct someone who doesn't know how to do what you propose :)

I'd word on that. Appreciate the advise.
